# angular routing: a weird error: Cannot read property 'path' of null

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I made a matcher function for a routing module, but I got a weird error:  Cannot read property 'path' of null, even if I check for the object existence.

```
export function contentMatcher(url) {
  //for simplifying, assume that all checks returned true
  return  {
        consumed: url,
        posParams: {
          type: new UrlSegment(url[0].path, {}),
          item: url[1] ? new UrlSegment(url[1].path, {}) : null //<------ Cannot read property 'path' of null
        }
      }   
}
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {  
    matcher: contentMatcher,
    component: ContentComponent
  }
]
```

I know that I must export the matcher function, because aot doesn't support function expression.
but I don't know if it is required also with posParams, and even so, how can I pass 'url' to it.

**solved**

the issue solved by replacing `item: url[1] ? new UrlSegment(url[1].path, {}) : null`
with `item:  new UrlSegment(url[1] ?url[1].path: null, {})`

Comment: That seems impossible: `null` is falsy, and the left branch shouldn't be evaluated. Are you sure the error isn't thrown by the line above?

Comment: I think your `url` function parameter is not an array, and when you try to get the `path` you got this error.

Comment: yeah, error must be on this line: `type: new UrlSegment(url[0].path, {}),`

Comment: No, the url is an array of one OR two elements, i.e url[0].path is always exists, but url[1].path may be not.  iI confirmed that the error is by the second line because when I remove it the code worked without errors.